# Assign start value explicitly to identity column

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I have below 2 tables (sybase ASE 15):

1. `TotalTradeCount = [count (int) ,client (varchar) ] => (325689,"XXX")`
2. `TodaysTrade = [ count (int,**identity**), Client, Tradetype,.... ]`

How do I assign `TodaysTrade..count = 325690` as a start value explicitly so that subsequent entries will have auto-incremental "count" by 1.

**Without using `sp_chgatttribute` and `set identity_insert on` as these require admin rights (sa role) which we don't have.**

Comment: Just Insert one dummy row and delete it. I will increase your identity column . Gl!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. have taken it into consideration....but have 1 doubt.. what if the sybase server restarts and identity column gets assigned to an abrupt value , so if we keep  "count" column as "numeric" instead of identity, then how do we assign a count from "TotalTradeCount" to "Todayscount..Count" as 325690. and auto increament by 1 ?

Comment: First of all, the idea of identity column is to provide a surogate key. I see no reason to change it manually. Otherwise if you require an column that will keep a proper count of rows you should calculate it durring the insert, i.e. 1. lock table in exclusive mode 2. calculate count as max(count) + 1 3. insert row. But having such solution is not an elegant  way. GL again!

Comment: Without using IDENTITY_INSERT, it doesn't appear (from documentation) that it is possible to just seed a specific identity starting value in Sybase. You will probably have to insert rows up to the value you need. http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X11817.htm and http://www.sqlines.com/sybase-asa/autoincrement_identity